# null exception in combineReducers after upgrading from Angular 2.x.x to 4

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've updated my application to Angular 4, which as I understand it shouldn't cause breaking changes to much, except animations.

However, my previously working application is failing with the exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at combineReducers (vendor.bundle.js:68589)
    at Object._initialReducerFactory [as a] (vendor.bundle.js:68531)
```

which appears to be caused by ng-rx store, which I've not updated (or changed the implementation of!).

I can break on the combineReducers line in chrome, and it calls the function first with my full list of reducers as I'd expect, twice, as part of compose and combineReducers (see code below). Then, randomly calls it again on a undefined reducers list.

Tracking back the call stack doesn't get me far. It's called from "AppModuleInjector", with the line:

```
  get _INITIAL_REDUCER_94():any {
    if ((this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_94 == null)) { (this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_94 = import8._initialReducerFactory(this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_93)); }
    return this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_94;
  }
```

where this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_93 is undefined. I've no idea what these things are, or where they originate from. I've only got two occurrences of combineReducers in my code:

```
const reducers = {
  profile: profileReducer,
  ..etc (this is what appears fine as a list of reducers the first function call)
};

const productionReducer: ActionReducer<AppState> = combineReducers(reducers);
const developmentReducer: ActionReducer<AppState> = compose(storeFreeze, combineReducers)(reducers);
```

I'm a bit lost as to what's gone wrong and what change in Angular 4 could have caused this. I've found nothing googling. Anyone know where to look further or what the issue might be?

**Edit:**

Interestingly, the offending reducer is called in `createInternal():import1.AppModule` by:

```
this._REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_28 = import38._createReduxDevtoolsExtension();
```

The reason it's null is that this is causing it to occur before the later:

```
this.__INITIAL_REDUCER_93 = import56.reducer;
```

Edit2: Took another look at the NPM install/packages. Seems there's something iffy. I'm getting unmet dependencies on a bunch of angular components:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ng2-pdf-viewer@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-calendar@0.7.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-calendar@0.7.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-calendar@0.7.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/effects@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngrx-store-localstorage@0.1.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-draggable-droppable@0.5.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-resizable-element@0.7.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

But I've got these in my packages.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "^0.0.32",
    "@types/compression": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/cors": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.43",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.54",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.48",
    "@types/node-uuid": "^0.0.28",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.7.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-jwt": "^3.3.0",
    "html-pdf": "^2.1.0",
    "http-proxy": "^1.16.2",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^1.0.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.9",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^0.1.5",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "0.0.6",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "normalizr": "^3.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-token": "^0.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typed-immutable-record": "0.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  }
```

I'm getting "unmet peer dependency" while installing said dependency:

C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\project>npm install @angular/core@4.0.0-rc.5 --save
angular2-express-starter@1.0.0 C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\project
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.0-rc.5
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.0-rc.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.0.0-rc.5

Comment: Prior to upgradation it was working fine?

Comment: Yep, no issues.

Comment: Check the package json if other node modules are also updated. If so this should be looked in the updated documentation

Comment: I think there's definitely something wrong with my packages.json, Getting NPM warnings: npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.

Comment: I have the same issue too. Still working on it as well.

Comment: If you find a solution, give me a shout. I'm wondering whether the large-number upgrade breaks existing libraries targeting 2. Like, @angular/core@4 does not fullfill an @angular/core@2 dependency.

Comment: That would be catastrophic if they're releasing a new version every 6 months though, as loads of libraries will become unusable unless constantly updated.

Comment: No need for panic. This is just one small set back, and it is not even on a real library. It is on a dev tool. After this I have no problem. The whole 2.4.x -> 4.X upgrade is smoother than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a solution undergoing now.

it is on [ngrx/store-devtools](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools/pull/55/commits/1f0b58020b4e635ab7f93fc231a0a7628f092e1c)

kudos to robertohuertasm@github

You can remove devtools to workaround this issue before they push a new release.

Comment: You're right, it's an issue with dev tools. Here's what worked for me: https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/357